# Easier way to get Google Maps Directions data into smartphone?

Tags: google-maps

I often use Google Maps Directions to draw routes before taking my bike, but it's a bit of a hassle to turn its data into a KML file and copy it into my smartphone:

1. Go to Google Maps Directions https://www.google.fr/maps/dir/
2. Draw route
3. Get and copy URL through the Menu button
4. Go to GPSVisualizer, paste URL, and get KML file
5. Copy KML file into smartphone (through either Windows Explorer or iTunes).

Is there an easier way, especially for non-geeks among my friends?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your preferred smartphone app you could use the Google Maps App and view your saved map there without having it to export as KML.

Otherwise you can skip the GPSVisualizer and export a KML from Google Maps directly when [saving the direction in My Maps](https://support.google.com/mymaps/answer/3502610?hl=en):

> - Open a new or existing map in [My Maps](https://google.com/maps/d/).
> - Click the directions icon in the toolbar.
> - Type your start and end locations. After, if you want, click Add Destination to add additional destinations.

After you saved your map you can [export it as KML](https://support.google.com/mymaps/answer/3109452?hl=en):

> - Click the map menu button  in the left panel.
> - Select Export as KML.
> - Choose the layer you want to export, or click Entire map.
> - Click Export.